# How to make an overlap 3d background in CSS?

Tags: html, css

![For example, look at how it's done here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WDF6.png)

I'd like to achieve something like this using CSS. How might this be done?

I like how the yellow background looks like it's 3d.

Comment: Did you get this from a website?

Comment: It's just two triangles in a darker shade of yellow absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, can't say I have the best solution, but here's my approach to the problem.

One way is to just slice up background images, and position them so you get the visual effect desired. Make the assets in PhotoShop (or your image editor of choice), then export it in pieces. A bit of absolute positioning, and you can have a banner that will work across most browsers without a lot of work. This isn't a particularly interesting approach though (and doesn't need much explanation), so let me propose something else.

A second way is a CSS-only solution, making use of the `:after` pseudo-class, and CSS triangles (if you want to read up more about triangles, [here's a link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)). Try breaking down the structure so you have a good idea of what the HTML would look like - I broke it down into the body, the main div (white), the banner area, and the banner's right/left edges. In code (note that I omitted the body):

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <p>Some content</p>
        <div class="banner">
            <span>I'm a banner!</span>
            <div class="left-edge"></div>
            <div class="right-edge"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now, the CSS is a bit more involved than just plain background images and colours. My approach works, but others could definitely write something a bit neater. Nonetheless, here's what I came up with (with a few stand-in values, like width, height, and colours):

```
body {
    background:#CCCCCC;
}
.main {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
}
.banner {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:#AAAAAA;
    position:relative;
}
.left-edge {
    background:#AAAAAA;
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:100%;
    left:-20px;
    top:0;
}
/* Triangle left */
 .left-edge:after {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:0 solid transparent;
    border-top:20px solid #777777;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:-20px;
}
.right-edge {
    background:#AAAAAA;
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:100%;
    right:-20px;
    top:0;
}
/* Triangle right */
 .right-edge:after {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:0 solid transparent;
    border-right:20px solid transparent;
    border-top:20px solid #777777;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:-20px;
}
```

The key elements behind this are the absolutely-positioned edge elements (positioned a negative distance equal to their width on the right/left of the banner), which have the same background colour as the banner so as to appear to extend it. The `:after` element for each of them is what makes the fake 3D effect; each of them results in a triangle, which is set to a different colour than the banner. The triangle positioning makes it look like the banner is wrapping around the main div, creating the 3D effect.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6YP4/3/) to show you a demo of the code.

Hope this helps! Again, this certainly isn't the only way, but it does address your problem. Let me know if you have any questions, and I'd be happy to try to help further.

Comment: I was going to post my own answer, but figured it would've been too similar to yours. Regardless, [here's my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/r6QPH/1/), which is more or less the same except for the code being more condensed.

Comment: Wow, yours is great, it's so short! I personally haven't done that much work with `:before` and `:after`, so I'm not the best at using them efficiently yet.